# display inline-block with 50% doesn't line up?

Tags: html, css, inline

i just want to create a simple horizontal list with some `divs`. Therefor i did this:

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ks0t1xoy/11/)

Now as you can see in the result the divs are not next to each other. But i used width of 50%. So what is wrong?

Comment: use `float:left;` instead of `display:inline-block;` or do [these tricks](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/)

Comment: @Alex float is good way but in question op asked issue with display:inline-block so better to stick with tricks given by you like margin-right:-4px will be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Elements with `inline-block` have a little margin on the right side. You can see this with this Code:

```css
div {
  background:black;
  display:inline-block;
  width:20%;
}
```

```html
<div>Test #1</div>
<div>Test #2</div>
```

**To solve your problem, you can use the following:**

```css
body, html {
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}
.list{
  width:100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: black;
}
.list div{
  float:left;
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100px;
  background: red
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
  <div style="background: red">1</div>
  <div style="background: orange">2</div>
  <div style="background: yellow">3</div>
  <div style="background: lightyellow">4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks. Didn't know that. Floats are a good alternative :)

Answer (score 0):

actually, this is a problem of `inline-block` so if you want to use it, you can't have whitespace between elements ;)

check your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ks0t1xoy/13/

after removing all whitespaces from your `.list` all elements align nicely, without touching your CSS